# Definition of "斬った張った"

Tags: meaning, words, definitions

I just have a quick question about some vocabulary, I've come across the phrase "斬った張った" in the following:

> 彼女や一郎{いちろう}の一族は栗沢川{くりざわがわ}で毎日斬った張ったを繰り返しており

However​, I've never seen the that phrase before, I couldn't find it in my dictionary either. I can take a guess at what it might mean from "斬" which refers to killing but I'd like to hear from someone who is more knowledgeable on this than I am since I want to know exactly what the sentence says, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

斬る is slashing, 張る in this context is slapping (cf [張り手](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8A%E6%89%8B)). 斬った張った (or 切った張った) is a bit dated set phrase that acts as a noun meaning such savage actions. It works also as a so-called no-adjective meaning *violent*, *savage*, *bloody*, etc. Monolingual dictionaries have an [entry for this](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%88%87%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E5%BC%B5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-480487). The context is lacking, but perhaps they are training hard at the riverside. It doesn't necessarily refer to physical violence, and you can say things like 株取引は切った張ったの世界だ.

Ta-form are used to express the action is completed (aka perfect aspect), and they're just there to add vividness and good rhythm. A similar set phrase is [惚れた腫れた](http://zokugo-dict.com/30ho/horetahareta.htm) which means "love affairs", 勝った負けた which means "winning and losing" or "gamble-like."

Answer (score 1):

You can find it [here](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%88%87%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E5%BC%B5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F)

I will parse the phrase:

> 斬っ: 連用形 of [斬る](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%96%AC%E3%82%8B) (cf. [促音便](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24033/19441))
>
> 張っ: 連用形 of [張る](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%BC%B5%E3%82%8B)
>
> た:archaic form of [たり](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A)

So, It literally means "slashing and strike" and by extension it means violence.

In this sentence 切った張った shows that 彼女や一郎の一族 is so barbaric.