# I don't get the meaning of 思うたより

Tags: usage, dialects, dialogue

I recently encountered the following sentence

> みんな思うたより緊張しとらんのぉ

I understand it means "everyone is less stressed than I expected." What I don't understand is why it is 思うたより rather than 思ったより. Is this to represent an accent/dialect here, like the のぉ
instead of なぁ? For the record, this character uses a bunch of stereotypical western stuff I think.

Comment: Does this https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3299/mukashi-banashi-do-they-borrow-from-other-current-dialects-in-addition-to-older/3312#3312 answer your question?

Comment: As @Nanigashi points out, this looks like the Kansai-ben variant for 思【おも】った.  This would fit with your comment that _"this character uses a bunch of stereotypical western (Japanese) stuff"_.

Comment: I would guess the speaker is from Okayama or Hiroshima, not Kansai.

Comment: I can confirm that this kind of usage also exists in Tosaben.